# Pulling a large data from internet which is best way to write into CSV file in python?

Tags: python, csv, large-files

I am trying pull all the DATA from a Google File.

If the response from Google is very large, I am getting a problem while writing the file into my CSV file.

```
try:        
    gc.disable()
    actList=[]  
    ofile  = open(file_loc, "w")  
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    actList.append(content)  
    writer.writerow(actList)  
    ofile.close()
    gc.enable()  
except BaseException as e:  
    print"THIS IS ERROR",e
```

Comment: +1 for using the built-in csv module. Please edit your question to include the error. It would also help to show a small sample of the data contained in `content`.

Comment: @bernie content is a very large file which contains 300 MB of Data which has(string,number,\n,"" and many things). Can't print all the data over here.

Comment: It seems a bit odd that you write all the 300 MB content into a *single* row. And your single row contains exactly *one* field (content). That's a pretty strange csv file. Is that intended?

Comment: @Helmut yes,I know its a internet content that I am getting.Need to write into CSV file.
Any better Option you can help me with ?

Comment: @bernie Helmut the content is a large file which gets downloaded from internet. What can be done that the content is fully fetched from the internet without errors.